# css unable to set display:block

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm unable to use css to set the display to block after i have used javascript to set it to none.

Is this normal or i'm missing something here?

```css
.lightbox:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```javascript
function onClickLightBox(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  target.style.display = "none";
}
lightbox.addEventListener('click', onClickLightBox);
```

I have had the same problem when using javascript set the display, Then @media was unable to change it once the screen resized.

Comment: Style rules declared **inline** will *always* over-qualify **external** or **internal** (styles in `<style>` tags) rules. With *one exception*, if you use an `!important` declaration (e.g: `display: block !important;`), you will over-qualify the *inline* style rule - so long as it (the *inline* style rule) doesn't have it's own `!important` declaration.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError at the moment my styles im setting in <style> should i move it to a css file?

Comment: You can keep your styles where ever you have them now, just keep in mind that whenever you use an *inline* style, it will over-qualify styles coming from anywhere else, so if you can't remove that inline style again, or apply the styles you need using a class (see Jeffrey's answer) then your only option is to use the `!important` declaration.

Answer (score 2):

The is normal.

Setting the `.style.*` properties sets the inline style.

Inline style is more specific than any selector.

Only an !important rule will override an inline rule (unless the inline rule is also !important).

Comment: an i cant over ride !important with java script, because dont seem to work

Answer (score 0):

```
target.style.display = "none"
```

should be:

```
event.target.style.display = "none";
```

---

As mentioned by Quentin, it adds an inline style, but I don't recommend it. You may need to use `!important`, which may make things even more confusing.

I recommend using CSS for styling, and add/remove/toggle a class to the current element through javascript.

Adding a class:

```
event.target.classList.add = 'myClass';
```

Removing a class:

```
event.target.classList.remove = 'myClass';
```

Toggle a class:

```
event.target.classList.toggle = 'myClass';
```

[Documentation on classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Comment: it was just a sample i slapped together just showing what i was doing. so was just a typo